# Idiomatic Functional Programming: Function which could result in error, but on success has no return value

Tags: functional-programming

Which is the more idiomatic function return type?

```
Option<ErrorType>
```

or

```
Either<ErrorType, void>
```

My gut feeling says the later makes more sense since it will generally be more compatible with other FP constructs, but it seems kind of weird that a `void` value will end up being the input to a function passed to a `map` or `chain` function.

Comment: I'm curious though why your function does not have a result? What does it do? For some kind of `hasError(value)` test I would indeed expect the `Option<Error>` type, for some kind of `validate` logic I would expect an `Either` with the valid input value as the right result.

Comment: In my case I'm validating some data structure. There's an error type returned if the data is malformed.

Comment: Yes, then I'd recommend `Either<Error, SomeDataStructure>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Either<ErrorType, Unit>
```

Or, depending on what language you're using:

```
Either<ErrorType, ()>
```

`Unit` is a type that contains exactly one possible value.  `void` has zero possible values, and therefore can’t be constructed, and therefore can't be returned as a result.

A `unit` value can be *‘picked out of thin air’*, always, because there's only one possible value.  Just like a `bool` can be picked out of *thin air* because `true` and `false` are the only two possible values.

However, `Unit` is a more natural fit here because you're saying *'there is no result so I'll return the bare minimum value, that contains no information other than: the operation succeeded'*.

Comment: I'm using typescript so I can probably just define something like`export type Unit = 1`

Comment: I haven't used typescript, but a more natural type would be an empty tuple (which is why in many languages unit is `()`) or you could use `{}` which would be an empty sum-type.

Comment: “An empty product type” I meant to say (not sum-type)

Comment: I ended up going with this for now. `export const SUCCESS = Symbol("Success");` `export type Success = typeof SUCCESS`. Then I can have an `Either<ErrorType, Success>`.